# Coded UI testing in multiple IE browser windows

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I am testing a chat client at a web service. I thought the best way to do this was to open the website in one internet explorer window, log in, open the chat. Then open a new IE window(in private mode so that the log in details will be forgotten) go the the page and then log in with another user and open the chat, and then start chatting with the other user in the other browser window.

The problem is when I have done everything in the first window and I open a new window, all actions are triggered in the first window even though the second window is selected. Is there any way to select which browser window to use? Or are there better ways to test this functionality without opening two internet explorer windows?

**Solved**: I solved this by opening a new window in private mode. When I wanted to do actions in that window I defined the browser window as:

```
        BrowserWindow privateWindow = new BrowserWindow();
        privateWindow.SearchProperties.Contains("[InPrivate]");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find some characteristic of the two IE windows that is different and ensure that it is included in the search criteria used to find the two windows. However modern browsers are complex, the distinction between windows and tabs it not always clear; window titles can change depending on which tab is selected.

Specific windows are selected by setting the properties of the `UITestControl` objects (and of derived objects). In the UI Map editor the properties panel has fields for the "Windows Title" and the "Search Criteria". For some controls there is also a "Filter Properties" field. The same fields are available if hand coding rather than recording tests.

Comment: The only difference I can find between the windows are the window title, which is dependent on the page. The window title of the window in private mode always ends with [InPrivate] (ex "Self Service Portal - Internet Explorer - [InPrivate]"). Is there a way to do: window.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name] = ..., to find the window that has a title that contains [InPrivate]?

Comment: yes there is a way: window.SearchProperties.Contains("[InPrivate]");